# Is there a single word for unhealthy ego?

Tags: terminology, psychology

This article actually explains my question http://stonepsychology.com/is-your-ego-healthy-or-unhealthy-heres-how-to-tell/ very well.

If we say some action is driven by 'ego' we often mean that the action is driven by excessive pride and coming from a place of unhealthy ego.

Is there any easier way that we can identify behaviours or actions as being driven by an unhealthy ego?   Is there a single word for 'unhealthy ego'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hubris

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubris):

> exaggerated pride or self-confidence

Hubris pretty much always has a negative connotation, unlike ego, which may be neutral, from its origins in [ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubris).

Answer (score 0):

You can identify those actions as **ego-driven**.

> Explanation:
>   To be ego-driven is that the person in question gets very well motivated by themselves.
>   They may also think that their actions are the best ones, and sometimes they may not consider other's actions.
>
> But in general... ego-driven is that the person has good confidence in themselves, and that they do not need support from others to reach their goals.
>
> It can sometimes be a *bad thing*, since they may get too self centered.
>
> <sub>[Source](https://socratic.org/questions/what-does-it-mean-if-someone-is-ego-driven)</sub>